# Laravel Artisan Migrate: "Error in cURL request: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: ssl, curl, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm running Laravel 4 on WAMP on Win 8.1.

The problem I'm having is that when I run

```
php artisan migrate
```

I get stuck on the error:

```
[Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Exception\RuntimeException]
Error in cURL request: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
certificate
```